# How to filter on antd table directly from firestore?

Tags: css, reactjs, node.js, firebase, antd

I am using an antd Table. I need to add filter to one column named User Type. I want userType column and this userType has TeachType and StudType as possible values. If the value is TeachType I want Teacher to be displayed and Student otherwise. The filter should be applied on this column. Say I click on Teacher all the records with TeachType as userType show get listed and if I select both all the records should get listed. This works when I pass the data directly to dataSource. Rather than using cached data, I want to perform this filter directly from the firestore database.

This below code works well, a proper default antd filter is shown with checkbox for Teacher and Student and with reset and ok buttons. This is only when dataSource is passed from already present data.

```
const columns = [
  {
      title: 'User ID',
      dataIndex: 'userId',
      key: 'userId',
      render: (_, record, index) => (
        <>
          <div>
              record.userId
          </div>
        </>
      ),
    },
  { 
      title: 'User Type',
      dataIndex: 'userType',
      key: 'userType',
      render: (text, record) =>
        text && text === TeachType
          ? 'Techer' :
          'Student',
      filters: [
        {
          text: 'Teacher',
          value: 'TeachType',
        },
        {
          text: 'Student',
          value: 'StudType',
        },
      ],
      filteredValue: filteredInfo.userType || null,
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.userType.indexOf(value) === 0,
    },
]
```

I want to query directly from firestore database. I came accross onFilterDropdownVisibleChange() which does it but I am not sure how to use it. I also dont want to distort the default dropdown I got when I used dataSource from chached data.

```
const columns = [
  {
      title: 'User ID',
      dataIndex: 'userId',
      key: 'userId',
      render: (_, record, index) => (
        <>
          <div>
              record.userId
          </div>
        </>
      ),
    },
  { 
      title: 'User Type',
      dataIndex: 'userType',
      key: 'userType',
      render: (text, record) =>
        text && text === TeachType
          ? 'Techer' :
          'Student',
      filters: [
        {
          text: 'Teacher',
          value: 'TeachType',
        },
        {
          text: 'Student',
          value: 'StudType',
        },
      ],
      filteredValue: filteredInfo.userType || null,
      onFilter: (value, record) => record.userType.indexOf(value) === 0,
 onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: async (visible) => {
// how do I get the selectedKeys values
// handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex, type)
 }
    },
]
```

I know we can get the values from :

```
filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => ()
```

Using this, I'll have to completely create the filter box with checkbox, button, functionality, everything from scratch. Is there a simple way to just take the values selected (Student, Teacher or both) and query firestore database based on these values on userType field and set it to say a variable which can then be sent to dataSource?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onChange` prop of table component, store filters in state if required then send request to server along with filters.

`onChange` function has 4 parameters. pagination, filters, sorter, extra (includes `currentDataSource` and `action ("paginate" | "sort" | "filter")`

You need to check if `extra.action` is `filter` then send the request to server with filters and load data.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'antd';

const dataSource = [
    { userId: '1', userType: 'TeachType' },
    { userId: '2', userType: 'StudType' }
];

const App = () => {
    const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([
        { userId: '1', userType: 'TeachType' },
        { userId: '2', userType: 'StudType' }
    ]);
    const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
        // Default filters if you want
        userType: ['TeachType']
    });

    const columns = [
        { title: 'User ID', dataIndex: 'userId' },
        {
            title: 'User Type',
            dataIndex: 'userType',
            filteredValue: filters?.['userType'],
            // No needed if data comes from server
            // onFilter: (value, record) => record.userType === value,
            render: (text, record) => (text === 'TeachType' ? 'Teacher' : 'Student'),
            filters: [
                { text: 'Teacher', value: 'TeachType' },
                { text: 'Student', value: 'StudType' }
            ]
        }
    ];

    return (
        <Table
            rowKey='userId'
            columns={columns}
            dataSource={dataSource}
            onChange={(pagination, filters, sorter, extra) => {
                if (extra.action === 'filter') {
                    setFilters(filters);
                    // Send request to server with filters
                    // const res = await fetch(...);
                    // setDataSource(res.data);
                }
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default App;
```

Hope this solve your problem